# What "chmod 777 -R / " does in /var/www/html/.../.../.../?

Tags: chmod

Unfortunately I was rushing and ran `sudo chmod 777 -R /` inside one project. Should I worry that it started to add 777 permission for all my folder starting from root (`/`) ?

Comment: if you actually typed `chmod 777 -R /` then everything is broken. `/` is the absolute path of the top level directory

Comment: Yeah, I am new in Linux, the price of learning. Thanks a lot, I will reinstall my computer.

Comment: Did you run it as root? (ie , logged in as root, or via `sudo chmod ...`) That could limit the damage done to the point where it might be reversible.

Comment: Ran it via sudo. But after it executed more then a second I just realized that something is wrong so I killed the execution. So basically it was running for 2-3 seconds. But I think I will reinstall my computer anyway :) Thank your for your answers

Comment: 1 second is more then enough ;-) But there are ways to fix it without reinstalling. See if what I posted works for you :)

Comment: @Tachyons: That's related but besides the point.

Answer (score 12):

> Should I worry that it started to add 777 permission for all my folder starting from root(/) ?

No, no need to worry. I can guarantee it if you used "sudo" in front of it or did a "sudo -i". Otherwise it should have shown a permissions error.

In case you want to restore your system there are ways to do this but you need a current (ie. up to date with your personal data) backup system. With [ACL tools](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl/) ...

- you can do `getfacl -R > permissions.txt` from `/` on the backup system to create a list of permissions.
- On the broken machine use a live session, copy the file to `/` and do `setfacl --restore=permissions.txt` in `/` to restore them.

I would advise you to re-install though.

Comment: Oh ! So nice to learn this. I will star this question for futur reference !

Comment: Leaving every file present on your local machine and not on the remote one with potentially broken permissions (world-write **and** world-execute, meaning even a completely untrusted account like `nobody` can alter an executable any other user might run) doesn't exactly strike me as adequate fix.

Comment: Oh yes I agree on that :-)

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you absolutely need to worry

You ran `sudo chmod 777 -R /`, which will recurse through the whole file system.

For most files, this is a minor inconvenience. For some files it will be a serious security risk (think `/etc/passwd`and the like), if some attacker manages to compromise your system via shell or CGI attacks.

But most importantly, some files *break* if they are too open. For example, if you open up `~/.ssh/*` (your ssh keys, authorized_keys, hosts...), then `ssh` or `sshd` will treat those files as if they were not there, for security reasons. This could, worst case, mean that you become locked out of your own machine, if you relied on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to log in via ssh+Public Key. There are also plenty of other security related software packages that do the same, mostly for their configurations in `/etc` or maybe some files in `/var`.

So while we obviously cannot say for sure as we know little about your machine. It is certainly not a harmless issue, as some of the other answers propose.

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
readlink -f /var/www/html/../../..
```

You'll get `/` it means as you said it your self your command has been run on the `/`, simply your system is broken now, get a backup of your data, re-install the Ubuntu.

`chmod`'s job is to change the mod (permission bit) of files/directories and `777` means every one can read, write, execute anything on your system, at the same time you have removed a lot of other bits like sticky, suid, sgid.

Comment: But only user root can do this. As a normal user, not much damage is done. Did OP run as root or not ?

Comment: Those are ellipses (i.e. `...`), not `..`. He probably meant he was in a long subdirectory under /var/www/html, when he ran the command passing it `/` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

On a point that hasn't been raised,

> ...it started to add 777 permission for all my folder starting from root...

You didn't just add 777 permissions, you removed the setuid, setgid, and sticky bit from all files. This'll cause things like `sudo` and `su` to stop working, since they rely on setuid to change users.

Note that `chmod 777` is short for `chmod 0777`. That other octal digit represents the bits I just mentioned. For example, `chmod 4777`, sets the setuid bit, clears the setgid and sticky bit, and adds all permissions.

In the future, I suggest using `chmod`'s other syntax:

```
chmod +rwx # what you probably intended
chmod ug+w # add write permission to user and group
chmod o-r # remove read permission from other
```