# Accidentally ran sudo chmod -R 664 / - completely locked out of my server, please help

Tags: 14.04, permissions, lamp, chmod

I can't believe I have done this but in my sleep deprived state (babies...) I have made an awful mistake on my server.

I cannot seem to do anything, navigate directories, restart the server, anything. I just get permissions denied errors.

Please tell me there is a way to recover from this or at least recover my data from my server?

Comment: did you do this WITH or WITHOUT -R?

Comment: Oh, whoops, typo. Yes I did it with -R   :(

Comment: Then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/940345/what-chmod-777-r-does-in-var-www-html/940350#940350 for starters and restore a backup for your personal data.  If this is a production server you really need to restore a backup.

Comment: And this is why Linux is a double-edged sword. The good part is it does exactly what you tell it to do. [The bad part is it does exactly what you tell it to do.](https://www.nixcraft.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/It-is-not-UNIXs-job-to-stop-you-from-shooting-your-foot.-If-you-so-choose-to-do-so-then-it-is-UNIXs-job-to-deliver-Mr.-Bullet-to-Mr-Footin-the-most-efficient-way-it-knows-e1477680104730.jpg)

Comment: Yes, well put and totally true.